Version control system for a large project
I need to create a repository for a large game on Unity, the size of which is not limited to 1 GB. It is desirable that such a repository be free (at least at the initial stage of development). I heard that GitHub can be used for such purposes, splitting a large project into parts that will be stored in several repositories. I created the main repository with the code and a repository with images to store the project images. The code is committed normally. But when I want to commit the images to the image repository, GitBash gives me a message that the histories of the local repository (with the project) and the remote repository (with images) do not match. And therefore it is impossible to push a commit. What should I do, how to make commits to the image repository and track image changes in the main project relative to the repository with images?

Are you looking for a system, or are you looking for a hosting service for that system? Those are very different requests.

"GitBash gives me a message that the histories of the local repository (with the project) and the remote repository (with images) do not match. And therefore it is impossible to push a commit." Please [edit] the question and copy/paste the session from the terminal: the command and the Git output; format as [code block] for readability.

Have you considered using Git LFS for the images? That's a much more efficient way to deal with large files in a Git repo.
